# Get float values back from byte buffer?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, buffer

I am learning C++ at the moment and currently I am experimenting with pointers and structures. In the following code, I am copying vector A into a buffer of size 100 bytes. Afterwards I copy vector B into the same buffer with an offset, so that the vectors are right next to each other in the buffer. Afterward, I want to find the vectors in the buffer again and calculate the dot product between the vectors.

```
#include <iostream>

const short SIZE = 5;

typedef struct vector {
    float vals[SIZE];
} vector;

void vector_copy (vector* v, vector* target) {
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        target->vals[i] = v->vals[i];
    }
}

float buffered_vector_product (char buffer[]) {
    float scalar_product = 0;
    int offset = SIZE * 4;
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i=i+4) {
        scalar_product += buffer[i] * buffer[i+offset];
    }
    return scalar_product;
}

int main() {

    char buffer[100] = {};
    vector A = {{1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3}};
    vector B = {{0.5, -1, 1.5, -2, 2.5}};

    vector_copy(&A, (vector*) buffer);
    vector_copy(&B, (vector*) (buffer + sizeof(vector)));

    float prod = buffered_vector_product(buffer);
    std::cout << prod <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work yet. The problem lies within the function `buffered_vector_product`. I am unable to get the float values back from the buffer. Each float value should need 4 bytes. I don't know, how to access these 4 bytes and convert them into a float value. Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `buffered_vector_product`, change the lines

```
int offset = SIZE * 4;
for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i=i+4) {
    scalar_product += buffer[i] * buffer[i+offset];
}
```

to

```
for ( int i=0; i<SIZE; i++ ) {
    scalar_product += ((float*)buffer)[i] * ((float*)buffer)[i+SIZE];
}
```

If you want to calculate the offsets manually, you can instead replace it with the following:

```
size_t offset = SIZE * sizeof(float);
for ( int i=0; i<SIZE; i++ ) {
    scalar_product += *(float*)(buffer+i*sizeof(float)) * *(float*)(buffer+i*sizeof(float)+offset);
}
```

However, with both solutions, you should beware of both the alignment restrictions and the [strict aliasing rule](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8).

The problem with the alignment restrictions can be solved by changing the line

```
char buffer[100] = {};
```

to the following:

```
alignas(float) char buffer[100] = {};
```

The strict aliasing rule is a much more complex issue, because the exact rule has changed significantly between different C++ standards and is (or at least was) different from the strict aliasing rule in the C language. See the link in the comments section for further information on this issue.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this "works" it's technically illegal pre c++20 because there is no float object living at that memory location.

Comment: @Frank: I am surprised to hear that, as this has been legal in C since at least C11. According to sentence 3 of [§6.5 ¶6 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6), the "effective type" of the object is `float`, despite it being stored in a `char` array (at least if you use `memcpy` or `memmove`, which OP does not do). I can't find an equivalent rule in the ISO C++ standard, though, neither in C++20 nor in C++17. Can you tell me what exactly has changed in C++20 that makes this legal?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  C++ simply does not have a notion of "effective type". A memory location can be interpreted as either the type of an object that was created there, or as a string of bytes. Copying memory around does not create equivalent objects. There HAS to be construction. The actual standard rules covering this is a combination of object lifetime and strict aliasing. The C++20 change in question is called "implicit creation of objects": http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html

Comment: @Frank: Thank you very much for that link. It is very interesting.